# Shrink LatLngBounds by 5%

Tags: android, google-maps, math

Alright so after reading Antonio's comment, I am with this in my code. Now regardless of what I submit as my percentage it still thinks my object is outside the bounding box.

My Position is the marker passed in.

```
LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
LatLngBounds newBounds = reduceBy(bounds, 0.05d);

        if(newBounds.contains(myPosition.getPosition())) {
            //If the item is within the the bounds of the screen
        } else{
            //If the marker is off screen
            zoomLevel -= 1;}
    }
    return zoomLevel;
}


public LatLngBounds reduceBy(LatLngBounds bounds, double percentage) {
    double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(bounds.northeast, bounds.southwest);
    double reduced = distance * percentage;

    double headingNESW = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(bounds.northeast, bounds.southwest);
    LatLng newNE = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(bounds.northeast, reduced/2d, headingNESW);

    double headingSWNE = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(bounds.southwest, bounds.northeast);
    LatLng newSW = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(bounds.southwest, reduced/2d, headingSWNE);

    return LatLngBounds.builder().include(newNE).include(newSW).build();
}

}
```

I have all the zoom levels set but sometimes I run into spots such as this where it is still in bounds except the marker is off screen. I want to have a slightly smaller bounding box to detect this and then zoom out one level on only these situations.

[image]

Comment: I avoided this at first thinking it was only for spherical calculations, my first test of it seemed to not work. The result was a box that appears smaller than all my outlying markers. O;

Comment: Reading your update I think that I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you post a sketch with your desired result?

Comment: Posted a screen shot, hope it makes sense. I assume LatLngBounds is the area edges.

Comment: If you build your `LatLngBounds` from your markers and then you shrink it, the markers in the border will always be outside the shrunk bounds (this is more clear if you have only two markers). I think that you need to take into account the camera bounds instead of your `LatLngBounds`

Comment: Why don't you just give a padding to your `LatLngBounds` when you create your `CameraUpdate`? `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100);`

Comment: This is how I was building my LatLngBounds, should have added it. LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

Comment: I started doing logs on every bit of coordinates data and I found an issue with my marker data, not sure why but I think that might be a bit of the source of my issues. Guess i'll be looking at that now haha

Comment: So your code worked for it, sorry this was confusing. I should update my question to explain. my LatLngBounds was pull the coordinates of a full zoomed out map. Even though it was in proper order the map hadn't zoomed in to get the proper coordinates. Ended up adding this.. mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SphericalUtil` class from the [Google Maps API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) to make the calculations:

```
public LatLngBounds reduceBy(LatLngBounds bounds, double percentage) {
    double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(bounds.northeast, bounds.southwest);
    double reduced = distance * percentage;

    double headingNESW = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(bounds.northeast, bounds.southwest);
    LatLng newNE = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(bounds.northeast, reduced/2d, headingNESW);

    double headingSWNE = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(bounds.southwest, bounds.northeast);
    LatLng newSW = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(bounds.southwest, reduced/2d, headingSWNE);

    return LatLngBounds.builder().include(newNE).include(newSW).build();
}
```

To reduce your bounds by a 5% (diagonal) you can do:

```
LatLngBounds newBounds = reduceBy(bounds, 0.05d);
```

Comment: I originally avoided this thinking it was for spherical bounding areas only. I threw it and it didn't work. It made my box shrink much small than all my points. Not sure where my mistakes is but in several hours I will work on it. I also realized tonight that a math formula won't work since there is many varying zoom levels so this is likely right. Anyway let me confirm before marking this correct. Thank you

Comment: Edited my post for the new issue, I am going through my code but still not getting the reduction to work properly.

Comment: There is a problem with that solution. But I can't explain it. I simply know that sometimes, based on your scroll position, will get a complete bad result.

Comment: @DennyWeinberg are you near longitude +/-180?

Comment: Possible. A client sent me a video about it. He scrolled between US and EU.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements for precision, you might want to just use simple interpolation like here:

```
public LatLngBounds reduceBounds(LatLngBounds bounds, double percentage) {
        double north = bounds.northeast.latitude;
        double south = bounds.southwest.latitude;
        double east = bounds.northeast.longitude;
        double west = bounds.southwest.longitude;
        double lowerFactor = percentage / 2 / 100;
        double upperFactor = (100 - percentage / 2) / 100;
        return new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(south + (north - south) * lowerFactor, west + (east - west) * lowerFactor),
                new LatLng(south + (north - south) * upperFactor, west + (east - west) * upperFactor));
    }
```

This is very simple Math using +-*/ and doesn't cost a lot of performance.

To reduce your bounds dimensions by 10% you do:

```
LatLngBounds newBounds = reduceBounds(bounds, 10);
```

Add error checking and border case handling as needed

Comment: I will check that version, since I'm having issues with the acceepted answer.